# Excel to Find Multiple Files and Attach to Email

Tags: vba, excel

My goal is to find all excel file names & paths, and all PDF files names & paths and compile them into a workbook (already done). Then take a reference number on one excel worksheet, find a corresponding excel filing using the file path listed on the same sheet. Then lookup the same reference number on two other worksheets in the same workbook to find the file path for the corresponding PDF and the email address(es) that I would send these files to. Then create an email, attach the documents, send to the listed recipient. The loop to the next row until complete.

I have already extracted all the excel and PDF information and compiled it into the worksheets. I figured my next step would be to try and take one excel file and create an email to the corresponding recipient. After getting that code down, I would build on it to then find the appropriate PDF and attach it to the email. Then finally to loop until every row is complete.

My issue is I cannot get past attaching an excel file and a corresponding email address. The excel files have their own subfolder, then every one has a folder named "scans", and then finally the .xlxs file with a varying name. I thought I'd accomplish this by using `Set rngAttach = wb.Sheets("Folder Output").Range("B2").Value & "\Scans\"` and then later adding the wildcard extensions `.Attachments.Add Replace(rngAttach.Value, "*.xlxs", "") & strFileName`.  However, I get an error here that my variables are not set, but I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Here is my full code, which may or may not work because I can't get far enough to find out.

```
Sub Email()

Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim cell As Range
Dim strbody As String
Dim rngAttach As Range
Dim wb As ThisWorkbook
Dim wsEmail As Worksheet

Set wsEmail = wb.Sheets("Emails")

'Set range for file attachment
Set rngAttach = wb.Sheets("Folder Output").Range("B2").Value & "\Scans\"

strFileName = Dir(rngAttach.Value)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

On Error GoTo cleanup

For Each cell In Columns("D").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" Then
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
        On Error Resume Next
        With OutMail
            .To = cell.Value
            .Subject = "Some Subject Line"
            .Body = "Dear "
           .Attachments.Add Replace(rngAttach.Value, "*.xlxs", "") & strFileName
            .Display  'Or use Send, Send will send the email without you seeing it, safer to use Display
        End With
        On Error GoTo 0
        Set OutMail = Nothing
    End If
Next cell

cleanup:
Set OutApp = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Any idea how I can approve upon this code?

I'd appreciate any advice on this. I've looked around the site and that is how I got the code to this point.

Comment: `rngAttach` is a `Range` - so get rid of the `.Value & "\Scans\"` when you `Set` it. You can tack the `"\Scans\"` onto `rngAttach.Value` when you are actually adding the attachment.

Comment: @BigBen thanks for the reply, and sorry for my delay in response. I just made the change you recommended, and I also realized that I didn't have `Set wb = ThisWorkbook` so I added that too. I don't get a debug error now, but it also doesn't seem to do anything at all.

Comment: Then comment out the `On Error Resume Next` and step through the code, and note any errors. If nothing's happening now, there's probably an error that you're just ignoring with `On Error Resume Next`.

Comment: @BigBen still nothing. I got rid of all error handling. I've tried F8 through the code but it just highlights almost every line, and I'm pretty sure my Sets are good.

Comment: What is your thinking behind `Replace(rngAttach.Value, "*.xlxs", "") & strFileName`? I'm confused why you need to replace, also should that be "xlsx"? You could also `Debug.Print Replace(rngAttach.Value, "*.xlxs", "") & strFileName` to see if it's exactly what you expect.

Comment: @BigBen I have realized some of my issues with the code. I'm not sure if it's fixed yet or not, but I will need to make some changes. My code was wrong for my thinking. I didnt want to replace, but add to. I think something like `rngAttach.Value & "scans\*xlsx"`.

Comment: @BigBen once I correct the stuff I'm aware of, I'll test it and update the code if needed. I'll let you know how it goes.